Why isn't my dehumidifier collecting water?
I adjust the humidity to 73 and the humidifier goes right back to 43. This is a Pelonis 50 pint dehumidifier with pump. It is two years old. The basement smells damp and there is no water collecting in pan. My filter is clean. There is nothing obstructing the air flow. Thanks for any suggestions in fixing this.


A dehumidifier will not operate at low temperature. What is the temperature of the basement? 2. What is the humidity in the basement? Measure it. Set the dehumidifier to a lower number.


If the basement smells damp, maybe you should look to see if there are actually and damp spots anywhere that might be causing this.

Is it running? Please revise to make the situation more clear.

Humidity should be between 30% and 50% with an ideal of 40%.  If you're currently at 43%, then you don't currently have a humidity problem.  You may still have a wetness problem if new water is seeping into the space.

If you set your dehumidifier to maintain 73% humidity and it measures the humidity at 43%, it won't turn on, because 43% is lower than 73%.
If you want to remove water from the air and it's measuring 43%, set it to 33% or 23%.
The measurement displayed might be inaccurate, (43% displayed may not be 43% in reality, because that shouldn't be musty/damp) but in any case for the thing to try to de-humidify the air it has to think the air needs de-humidifying.
This is like asking why your air conditioner does not turn on when set to 73 degrees if it's 43 degrees in the house according to the air conditioner's thermostat.

The humidity sensor may be broken. It's also possible, depending on the climate and amount of ventilation, that the air in the basement is quite dry but the smell of damp is coming from a small patch of a surface that's wetter, or even up from below (I wonder what the basement floor is). That smell csn be released as things warm up.

Setting it really low (mine has a continuous mode, like setting a target of 0 RH) is a good test. If it's working and the humidity is low, it will collect a little water. If it's working and the humidity is high it will collect a lot. If it's not working, it won't collect any, though the fan and even the compressor may run

Invest $10 in a hygrometer (humidity meter).  That will set your direction ... dehumidifier is wrong, or, if it's right, you should ignore it and look for the source of the smell.   43% is dry enough that you should not have smells unless you have some lingering rotten material somewhere.    If you bought the machine recently and you have a long-standing dampness problem, you should set it to its lowest setting and leave it running a few months before worrying further.
